# Correct way to set the path of a BackgroundImage in JavaFX CSS

Tags: css, javafx-2, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I have an **AnchorPane** and I want to style it by giving it a BackgroundImage I have in another package : 
[image: File Structure Screenshot]

Here's the CSS I tried:

```
#body 
{
    -fx-background-image:url("/Images/FlowersPattern_beige_background.jpg");   
}
```

Using javascript I set the AnchorPane's CSS id to `body`; that didn't work. I tried to check other questions already asked, but they didn't help. Please can you clarify how, exactly, it should be done?

Comment: What do you mean with "Anchopan"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your `css` file is loaded normally, Replacing:

`"/Images/FlowersPattern_beige_background.jpg"`

with

`"../Images/FlowersPattern_beige_background.jpg"`

should work.

The path is relative to the `css` file's directory, the `..` accesses the parent directory (`src`); `/Images` refers to the  *Images* directory; finally `/FlowersPattern_beige_background.jpg` accesses your image.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought I tried to include "src" in the path but it didn't work, this works though, thx a lot